# SIP on different networks

Tags: android, video-streaming, sip, voip, lan

I am making an Android application to connect to devices with SIP. After connection, caller send video-streaming to receiver and all work well in the same LAN, but I can not make it working on different network or cellular network; the call is working but video don't works, I thinks because public IP don't launch private IP where video is sending. Can you help me? Do I need STUN or something similar?

Another question about this, would it be functional with a SIM with public IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given that the number of users I require is limited, I have chosen to implement a VPN since the only communications allowed are between users of the application. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the SDP in the SIP INVITE and SIP 200 OK (for INVITE) contains IP addresses that are only valid in your own network. Lets say the User Agent Server (=UAS) is situated in a 10.x.x.x private network and your User Agent Client (=UAC) is situated in a 192.168.x.x private network. So, the UAS will receive a SIP INVITE containing 192.168.x.x as media destination in the SDP. Since private IPs are "non-routeable" via a public network (of course, since they're private) the UAS is not able to send the audio/video stream to the UAC and vice versa.

Possible solution is to use a STUN server. So UAC/UAS are able to find out their public IP addresses -> see this [link](https://www.3cx.com/blog/voip-howto/stun-voip-1/).

Another alternative may be the use of IPv6 addresses, since they're unique on a global level. Based on that NAT should not be a problem with IPv6.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution

Comment: @poly82: Was the answer correct? If so, please mark the question as solved. Thx